# Find a specified folder within a whole partition

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory

I need to find a specified folder which can be located anywhere on the disk.
I wonder what would be the fastest solution to do this with a Python 3.4.

I know folder name, for example "XXX" and it's subfolder "YYY". And for not to be easy, there are many folders called "XXX" but none of them contains "YYY" folder. So it's quite unique.

I wanted to walk on C: and find folder "XXX" and if it is found then check if it contains "YYY".
But maybe there is some kind of library which can speed this up or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import os

partition = input("Which drive do you want to search? ")
dirname = "XXX"
subdirname = "YYY"
for root, dirs, _fnames in os.walk(partition):
    if os.path.basename(root) != dirname: continue
    if not os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root, subdirname)): continue
    print("Found required folder:", root)
    break
```

Comment: Basicly, os.walk() enters every folder in path, and then every subdir for every folder and deeper and deeper?

Comment: @jotto: [that is correct](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.walk)

Comment: That is what I wanted to know. Thanks :)